# Provide an example of a function whose inverse is also it's derivative.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a question from a mathematics competition. I'm totally stumped with this one. If anyone could give an example, or even better, show working, that would be great.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean functional or multiplicative inverse?

Comment: When you mean the functional inverse, see here:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f/34095#34095

Comment: I think functional. In the sense of y=ln x being the inverse of y=e^x.

Comment: Why would this need clarification? It's the functional inverse. I've never seen anyone (except for clueless students) saying the inverse of $f$ is $\dfrac 1 f$, except for when there is some underlying algebraic structure, which isn't the case at all.

Comment: @GitGud Well G.T.R below thought it was the multiplicative inverse

Comment: @GitGud +1; $\frac1f$ is the reciprocal of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks for $f$ such that:

$$
f'(x) = f^{-1}(x)
$$

You can search for it in polynomial form $f(x) = Cx^\alpha$:
$$
C\alpha x^{\alpha-1} = \left(\frac{x}{C}\right)^{1/\alpha}
$$

So that equality of constants and powers asks for:

$$
C^{1+1/\alpha}\alpha = 1 \Rightarrow C = \alpha^{\frac{1}{1+1/\alpha}}
$$
$$
\alpha -1 = \frac{1}{\alpha} \Rightarrow \alpha = \frac{1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}
$$

The equation has a solution, so it gives an example.

Comment: this is the basically the same answer given here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34052/function-satisfying-f-1-f/34095#34095

Answer (score 0):

Consider y'=y^-1 as your problem.  This DEQ is invariant to the infinite continuous group X=tx, Y=(t^.5)y, where t ranges from zero to infinity.  This Lie group admits an autodiffeomorphism of y'=y/2x.  Setting this equal to 1/y, you get y=(2x)^.5, which is a solution to your equation.  I realize this is like swatting a fly with a sledgehammer, but it was a lot of fun to calculate.  Thanks!